# How to have more than 2 clone views in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Is it possible to have more than 2 (3 or 4) clone views of a file in the same Notepad++ instance?

If yes, how? Are there any plugins for this purpose?

Comment: I wish this was the case as a native function of Notepad++, but I don't think this is so. I ended up downloading Programmer's Notepad so that I could have a lightweight copy of my file open side by side.

Comment: @Ryan notepad++ permits 2 clone views. Does Programmer's Notepad permit more than 2 clone views?

Comment: I'm not sure how to clone view in Programmer's Notepad. I'm very new to it.

Comment: I wanted to do the same with Notepad++ open multiple files each in it's own view, not instance. Since it's not possible i've switched to Sublime2 editor which allows for multiple files to be open in their own panel

Comment: I want 3 views of the same file in one instance so editing one view instantly updates the other 2 views. This would be ideal for HTML editing: 1st view on the style section, 2nd view on the script section, 3rd view on the HTML section. Bouncing up and down for cross-referencing all the time really slows down the workflow.

Answer (score 6):

There's neither a functionality like this in or a plugin for Notepad++ as of yet.

For what it's worth, the next best thing would be multiple instances. You can always open another instance of Notepad++ by either

- appending the `-multiInst` command line switch to a Notepad++ shortcut or
- right-clicking on a tab and selecting `Open in new instance`

Comment: Just a hint: Instead of appending the shortcut, running `notepad++ -multiInst` may be better for one time use.